# publish_actions right for my dev and test users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-permissions

At this time i still have the same issue as lot of us with my test and dev users.

My aggregation is ok, the new auth dialog is active, 
publish_action set in Auth dialog permissions page.

But it still show the old auth dialog for new dev/test user, 
and no publish_actions for already signed users (test and dev). Any solution to this?
I'm stuck on this for a day now...
Thank you

Comment: Please provide the code for generating and granting the new permissions

Comment: Thank you, but i do not understand wich code i must provide and how/where to generate it. Can you give me more precisions. Thank you for the help

Comment: One more thing i have to say , is that with my admin account I CAN PUBLISH actions !!! That's only dev and test users who can't! So i think that my PHP code is good, it's a problem on the configuration somewhere in the dev app

Comment: Is it this code you need ?


curl -F 'access_token=AAAEwlOCAiW4BAL1wZCckgl3oXlueAHpgxzkt1XYZBZAZA09QzlIFyVmMZBoqpAIILSW7MGmXS7ZArOB1wP4QpQLO2PQMS2STq8kWT9ETXpRgZDZD' \
     -F 'gift=http://samples.ogp.me/335402573139391' \
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me/zewishlist:wish'

Comment: An other point unclear for me there is an action/object use/website automatically added by FB. I dont know how to populate the aggregation preview, wich is, if badly defined a problem for accessing publis_action i suppose. So i desabled the 'social discovery' option in the advanced app params. But i still not have the new Auth Dialog box for mes dev and test users

Comment: @smit is it this code you need ? /me/zewishlist:wish/gift?gift=http://samples.ogp.me/335402573139391 i think that the problem is that i can't have enhanced auth dialog working, it's still the old auth dialog